# How to prevent Visual Studio project setting overriding command line SET CL options

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, cl

I need to build a Visual Studio 2012 project unchanged using Visual Studio 2015 and am finding that Visual Studio 2015 seems to have changed rules and now a Windows API function is deemed deprecated.  I have found I can change compile options via the command line using SET CL but this command line options is being overridden.

I need to find a way to force the command line option to be used.

Here is the source code:

```
/*
1>e:\code\compile_cmd_line\main.cpp(15): warning C4996: 'GetVersionExA': was declared deprecated
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\sysinfoapi.h(433): note: see declaration of 'GetVersionExA'
*/

// with below line uncommented, builds in Visual Studio 2015 IDE ok
// #pragma warning(disable: 4996)  // error C4996: 'GetVersionExA': was declared deprecated

#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    OSVERSIONINFOA vi = { };
    BOOL ret = GetVersionExA(&vi);
}
```

The compiler options in the project file are:

```
/GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\compile_cmd_line.pch"
```

The problem settings are SDL checks /sdl and Security check /GS

Here is how I try to compile using VS2015:

```
E:\code\compile_cmd_line>set CL=/sdl- /GS-

E:\code\compile_cmd_line>devenv /useenv /build "Release|x86" compile_cmd_line.sln

Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25420.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

The license for Visual Studio expires in 20 days.
1>------ Build started: Project: compile_cmd_line, Configuration: Release Win32
------
1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/sdl-' with '/GS-'
1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GS-' with '/sdl'
1>  main.cpp
1>main.cpp(20): error C4996: 'GetVersionExA': was declared deprecated
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\sysinfoapi.h(433): note:
see declaration of 'GetVersionExA'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

E:\code\compile_cmd_line>
```

The problem lines:

```
1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/sdl-' with '/GS-'
1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GS-' with '/sdl'
```

For completeness, I have a setup script to setup the env vars for the MS build tools:

```
call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"

set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;%INCLUDE%
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86;%LIB%
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Can I force the override using SET CL?

Comment: Is it actually not feasible to edit the `vcxproj` file, or is the requirement just that you need to compile under both Studio Versions?

Comment: I could make a separate folder for VS2015 and put a changed project file in there.  Problem is the code is shared across multiple teams and want to make as few changes as possible right now and just fix in build stage using cmd line

Comment: It is [relatively straightforward](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/360792/6559) (but not trivial) to do a few manual edits in the `vcxproj` file so that it compiles with different options on multiple studio versions. May be an option for you.